# Fetching multiple columns of a database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I needed to grab one full column of a database and only that column, and have it returned as an array. I was using `$qarr1 = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);`, which worked perfectly. I now need to pull a second column from that data and have it saved as a separate array, but I can't use `fetchAll()` for this because of cursor problems. I am still brand new to PHP and don't quite understand the whole concept of the cursor, and I'm having difficulty understanding the arguments for [`fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php). Is someone able to explain what I could do instead of using `fetchAll()`?

Comment: have you tried $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); ?

Comment: That returns the *entire* database. Is there a way to avoid that, or is it not really a problem? Also, each row is sorted into an array rather than each column, if I'm interpreting the output from `print_r()` correctly.

Comment: if you only need to return certain columns why dont you do that on query side like SELECT col1, col2 and will get only those 2 columns

Comment: `I can't use fetchAll() for this because of cursor problems` ... what do you mean?

Comment: When I use `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN,0); fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN,6);`, the second array is empty. From what I understand, this is because the MySQL cursor has progressed to the end of the database, so there's nothing left for it to fetch.

Comment: Why do you need 2 separate arrays? Why can't you use one holds both columns?

Comment: Is there a way to make one of the fetched columns a key column? If so, I could adjust the query and do it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using `$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`
but if you really want to avoid `fetchAll()` then just loop through each row.

```
$arr = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $arr[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: fetchAll needs more resources. Moreover, if you need to modify array keys while getting results back you cant do it with fetchAll you will still need to loop through all

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is to use `PDO::FETCH_NUM` to grab all results similar to `FETCH_ASSOC` but instead of an associate index you will have number index  and then use the php function `array_column(myArray, columnNumber)` so you can grab each column to any variable you want. Here you have a code example:

```
// grab all columns and put index numbers for each column
$allColumns = $user_database->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

// grab first column
$con = array_column($allColumns, 0);
// grab second column
$gan = array_column($allColumns, 1);

// this will output the variables so you can see what was grabbed   
echo '<pre>$con:  '; var_dump($con); 
echo '<pre>$gan:  '; var_dump($gan);
```

I hope this helps.